# Don't understand this output

Tags: python

```
n = 1000
s = [2] + [i for i in range(3, n, 2)]
sq = int(s[-1] ** 0.5 + 1)
if sq % 2 == 0:
    dex = s.index(sq-1)
else:
    dex = s.index(sq)

for i in range(1, dex):
    print(i, dex)
    for j in s:
        if j % s[i] == 0 and j != s[i]:
            s.remove(j)
            if j <= sq:
                dex = dex - 1

#print(len(s))
```

This is a simple script to count primes below `n`. It works but it seems to go a few rounds too many and I'm trying to optimize it. Anyway, I found some output that I don't understand. In this script, how can `i` take a value greater than `dex`?

Answer (score 0):

> how can `i` take a value greater than `dex`?

The `range` object is created once, before the `for` loop process starts, and uses the value that `dex` had at that time. Subsequently, `dex` decreases.

Comment: This makes sense! Is there a way to decrement within the ```for``` loop?

Comment: I don't understand your intended logic, mostly because I can't guess what these variable names are supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

`range(1, dex)` returns a sequence of numbers starting from `1` to `dex - 1`, so if you change the value of `dex` after that (as in your case inside the loop), that will not affect the sequence that's already been generated before (number of iterations the loop will go through).